Return arrays where arrays data inside them occurs only once
Given the following array of multiple arrays, I would like to return all arrays where their data isn't duplicated in other arrays.
For example $a['test'] array should only contain arrays with keys 1,2,4,5,8 because their values aren't duplicated in other arrays.
I am looking into array_filter function at the moment, but can't quite get it right.
Thanks
$a['test'] = [
    1 => [
        'key_1' => 1,
        'key_2' => 2
    ],
    2 => [
        'key_1' => 7,
        'key_2' => 8
    ],
    3 => [
        'key_1' => 1,
        'key_2' => 2
    ],
    4 => [
        'key_1' => 5,
        'key_2' => 6
    ],
    5 => [
        'key_1' => 3,
        'key_2' => 4
    ],
    6 => [
        'key_1' => 1,
        'key_2' => 2
    ],
    7 => [
        'key_1' => 5,
        'key_2' => 6
    ],
    8 => [
        'key_1' => 9,
        'key_2' => 10
    ]
];

And this is how I would like the array to look like after processing
$a['test'] = [
    1 => [
        'key_1' => 1,
        'key_2' => 2
    ],
    2 => [
        'key_1' => 7,
        'key_2' => 8
    ],
    4 => [
        'key_1' => 5,
        'key_2' => 6
    ],
    5 => [
        'key_1' => 3,
        'key_2' => 4
    ],
    8 => [
        'key_1' => 9,
        'key_2' => 10
    ]
];


array_filter isn't terribly suited for this, because that looks at one array element at a time. You're better off loping over your input array and populating a helper array, where you use the combination of the key_1 and key_2 values as the key (encode them as JSON, to get a unique string value for each combination) - if an entry with the key combination for the current element already exists, then you don't add it again.
foreach($a['test'] as $item) {
    $key = json_encode($item);
    if(!isset($helper[$key])) {
        $helper[$key] = $item;
    }
}
$a['test'] = array_values($helper);;

print_r($a['test']);

Result:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key_1] => 1
            [key_2] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [key_1] => 7
            [key_2] => 8
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [key_1] => 5
            [key_2] => 6
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [key_1] => 3
            [key_2] => 4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [key_1] => 9
            [key_2] => 10
        )

)

If you need to retain the original array's indexes in the result, then stick them into the data as well, so that you can restore them from there afterwards.
foreach($a['test'] as $akey => $item) {
    $key = json_encode($item);
    if(!isset($helper[$key])) {
        $helper[$key] = [$akey, $item];
    }
}
$a['test'] = array_combine(array_column($helper, 0), array_column($helper, 1));

print_r($a['test']);

Result:
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [key_1] => 1
            [key_2] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [key_1] => 7
            [key_2] => 8
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [key_1] => 5
            [key_2] => 6
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [key_1] => 3
            [key_2] => 4
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [key_1] => 9
            [key_2] => 10
        )

)


I guess this is a bit extra to ask, but would it be possible to filter these results only based on certain key value pairs? For example have the results to include all array keys, but the filter should only be made on key_1 values. In short keep all of the arrays where key_1 values are different. Thanks

The key of the helper array decides, what this gets grouped by. Since your initial requirement was using all the sub-array items for the grouping, I just encoded the whole element as JSON, to use as key. If you need this for only one single property, you can use that as key directly, $key = $item['key_1']; - no JSON encoding necessary, because there can be no "overlap" of different key values. If you need to group by more than one property - then "list" those as an array explicitly, and encode that as JSON. $key = json_encode([$item['key_1'], $item['key_4654'], ...]);

The JSON encoding (or some form of "structured" data format) is necessary when you are using multiple grouping properties. If you were to just concatenate them to each other without any structure, or separator character between them - then key_x=5 and key_y=67 would result in a "grouping key" of 567, but so would key_x=56 and key_y=7, although those of course would need to be considered different groups, and not the same one.

array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR) is the most elegant way to remove duplicates whole rows from your input.  This is shown on both dupe targets.  Filtering by one column is demonstrated several ways on the second dupe target.

You could just keep track of those you've checked already and unset those who exist in the $seen list:

Loop over all the nested items

Check if the values exist in our helper list

true:  unset the current key
false: array_push the current values



$seen = [];

foreach ($a['test'] as $k => $v) {
    $vals = array_values($v);

    if (count(array_intersect($vals, $seen))) {
        unset($a['test'][$k]);
    } else {
        array_push($seen, ...$vals);
    }
}

var_dump($a['test']);


Try it online!
